# Solr confusion - how to include a customized tokenizer into solr.war?

Tags: solr

I am new to solr and i am working with it using solr 3.6, eclipse and tomcat.

Baiscally I need to write a customized tokenizer and use it for both indexing and searching, so i think i need to include it into solr.war, schema.xml and maybe solrconfig.xml? Searching around the web, i dont find any quick tutorial. Write a tokenizer to extend the generic Tokenizer class can be simple, but how to make it compiled and included into solr.war? people said on the web that i can write the tokenizer and include it in solr's classpath, but what's solr's classpath then...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @javanna i know you are the expert, can you please give me some suggestions on how i can get a start on this? thanks a lot!! :)

Comment: There's no need to mention me on every question you ask :) even because I don't receive a notification if I'm not involved in the question. I'm not the only expert here, anyway I read all solr questions daily, no worries!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- create a jar with your tokenizer

  < lib dir="../add-everything-found-in-this-dir-to-the-classpath" />
- add in solrconfig.xml an element pointing to the dir where you have the jar
- include the tokenizer in the schema.xml as any other tokenizer

Look at the example\ dir in 3.6 distribution.

edit: sample for lib element was invisible

Comment: Thanks a lot, Albert! I will try this first. Actually I wanna build solr.war with this jar. If i use Eclipse, does this mean that i need to create a eclipse project and add all the solr libs(jars) and then add my tokenizer to build it? Sorry to ask basic questions, i was a c# dev and all these open source things are new to me...

Comment: if you want to add it to eclipse war you need to build the war somehow, whether you do it by hand (war can be opened just like a zip) or eclipse or ant etc is up to you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i will see if i can make it...too bad that there isn't any clear documentation on how to get it done.

Comment: i created a web app and able to import solr.war and run it with tomcat now.